# get all data of multiple worksheet in google api in js

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get some data from google sheet using javascript. There is multiple worksheet in my sheet. I'm successfully getting all data for single worksheet. But i need to get all data from all worksheet. Here is my code for single worksheet.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheet_id}/values/sheet1?key={API_KEY}',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {

    }
});
```

Can anyone help me to get all data for all worksheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that in your current situation, you are using spreadsheets.values.get method of Sheets API. When you want to retrieve all values from all sheets, for example, how about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, it uses spreadsheets.get method of Sheets API. In this case, all values can be retrieved by the following endpoint.

Endpoint:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###?fields=sheets%2Fdata%2FrowData%2Fvalues%2FuserEnteredValue&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

- Fields of `sheets/data/rowData/values/userEnteredValue` is used for retrieving the values.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, it uses spreadsheets.values.batchGet method of Sheets API. In this case, you are required to know each sheet name, because the sheet name is used in this method.

Endpoint:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###/values:batchGet?ranges=Sheet1&ranges=Sheet2&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

- As the query parameter, please set it like `ranges=Sheet1&ranges=Sheet2&...`.

#### Note:

- In your script, you use API key. In this case, the Spreadsheet is required to be publicly shared.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

### Edit:

- You selected the pattern 2.
- You want to create the query parameters by retrieving all sheet names in the Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about retrieving the sheet name using spreadsheets.get method of Sheets API. The endpoint is

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###?fields=sheets%2Fproperties%2Ftitle&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In this case, `sheets/properties/title` is used as `fields`. By this, all sheet names can be retrieved. When this is reflected to your script, how about this modification? I think that this is a simple modification. So please modify it to your situation. And I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###?fields=sheets%2Fproperties%2Ftitle&key={API_KEY}',
  async: false,
  success: function(response) {
    const queryParams = response.sheets.reduce((s, e, i) => s += "ranges=" + e.properties.title + (i < response.sheets.length - 1? "&" : ""), "");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###/values:batchGet?key={API_KEY}&' + queryParams,
      async: false,
      success: function(r) {
        console.log(r)
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i just can't hard-code ranges. Its dynamic.

Comment: @Alauddin Ahmed Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I couldn't understand about ``i just can't hard-code ranges. Its dynamic.``? Can I ask you about your current issue? I would like to resolve your issue. But I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: I meant, i can't just hard-code ranges=sheet1&ranges=sheet2 like this.. those worksheet names may change.

Comment: @Alauddin Ahmed Thank you for replying. I apologize for my incomplete answer. I could understand about your current issue. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Sorry, Didn't check the answer.. your previous answer given me the hint that i needed. And i did exactly the same of your current answer..

Comment: There is a problem.. The second ajax call not getting all data in live server, But working fine locally. what could be the problem?

Comment: @Alauddin Ahmed Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue of ``The second ajax call not getting all data in live server, But working fine locally. what could be the problem?``, I cannot understand about the situation. So can you post it as new question? By this, many users can think of your issue and solution. For this situation, I apologize for my poor skill.